# Compare peformance bulkloader with load data infile MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, load-data-infile, bulkloader

I build an `C#` application which need to insert 200k records into `MySQL`. I found `bulkloader` and `load data infile`, so my question about performance of them. Which way is faster, or they are the same?

Comment: Which bulkloader? MySQL Connector/Net features a bulk loader class that wraps the MySQL statement LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: I mean MySqlBulkLoader. Do you think they are the same?

Comment: According to the above statement I copied from mysql website, they are the same.

Comment: By the time you get this answer, you could have used either on a dozen times.  200K records will take seconds, maybe minutes.  (I assume this is a 1-time task?)